# Testdome "Path" Python - Can't determine why my solution isn't 100% correct

Tags: python

So I'm using `testdome`'s public [questions](https://www.testdome.com/questions/python/path/8735) to practice python and one of them is this path problem. I can only get 50% on the solution and I can't figure out why. I can't even create a test of my own that fails.

```
class Path:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.current_path = path

    def cd(self, new_path):
        new_path_list = new_path.split('/')
        for item in new_path_list:
            if item == '':
                self.current_path = '/'
            elif item == '..':
                self.current_path = self.current_path[:-2]
            else:
                self.current_path = self.current_path + '/' + item

        if '//' in self.current_path:
            self.current_path = self.current_path.replace('//','/')
```

Edit: Updated code based on first response. Still 50% though.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, where you have

```
for item in new_path_list:
    if new_path_list[0] == '':
```

what you meant was

```
for item in new_path_list:
    if item == '':
```

**Edit:** I thought I'd try it myself; here's how I did it (scores 100%):

```
# https://www.testdome.com/questions/python/path/8735

ROOT = "/"
DIV = "/"
PREV = ".."

class Path:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.dirs = []
        self.cd(path)

    @property
    def current_path(self):
        return str(self)

    def cd(self, path):
        if path.startswith(ROOT):
            # absolute path - start from the beginning
            self.dirs = []
            path = path[len(ROOT):]

        # follow relative path
        for dir in path.split(DIV):
            if dir == PREV:
                self.dirs.pop()
            else:
                self.dirs.append(dir)

    def __str__(self):
        return ROOT + DIV.join(self.dirs)


path = Path('/a/b/c/d')
path.cd('../x')
print(path.current_path)
```

Comment: That's definitely a part of it. I think I was doing that to try to get rid of the double '//' if your cd string starts with a '/'. Looking at it now that would be true for all of the items in that case though. Thanks. I'll updat the code in my question, but still only get 50%

Answer (score 0):

```
root='/'
div='/'
parent='..'

class Path:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.current_path = path
        self.current = path.split('/')


    def cd(self, new_path):
        if new_path[0]=='/':
            self.current_path= "/"
            self.current= ['']
        new_path_list = new_path.split('/')

        for item in new_path_list:
            if item != '' :
                if item == parent:
                    self.current.pop()                    
                else:
                    self.current.append(item)
                self.current_path = div.join(self.current)

path = Path('/a/b/')
path.cd('../x')
path.cd('/a/b')
print(path.current_path)
```

Comment: Please, explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning Python recently, thanks for ppl who replied above which are really helpful for newbie!

I created my own 100% resolution, share it here to be another reference for any newbie like me :

```
class Path:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.current_path = path

    def cd(self, new_path):
        PREV = '..'
        DIV = '/'

        #c_list = ['', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        c_list = self.current_path.split(DIV)
        #n_list = ['..', 'x']
        n_list = new_path.split(DIV)

        for item in n_list:
            if item == PREV:
                #delete the last item in list
                del c_list[-1]
            else:
                c_list.append(item)
        #add "/" before each item in the list and printout as string                    
        self.current_path = "/".join(c_list)
        return self.current_path


path = Path('/a/b/c/d')
path.cd('../x')
print(path.current_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same, same, but different...

```
class Path:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.current_path = path

    def cd(self, new_path):
        if new_path[0] == '/':
            self.current_path = new_path
        else:
            for part in new_path.split('/'):
                if part == '..':
                    self.current_path = '/'.join((self.current_path.split('/')[:-1]))
                else:
                    self.current_path = self.current_path + '/' + part
```

Comment: path.cd('/x/..') failed

Comment: path.cd('./x/..') failed